# Different Action every time the same button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a whole bunch of images across the screen that are currently hidden with CSS. I also have a button in the direct center of the screen. I'd like to have a function that unhides another image every time you click it. This seems to be just out of my experience level with JavaScript.

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? You haven't included any code.

Comment: Ok, nice. But, what U have until now? Any code?

Comment: Can you include the code you have attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get going. You should have provided some code though.

```js
function showimage() {
  var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
  
  //if there are any images left to show
  if(imgs.length > 0) {
    var img = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length)];
    img.className = "shown";
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.shown {
  display: unset;
}
```

```html
<img class="hidden" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="" />
<img class="hidden" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="" />
<img class="hidden" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="" />
<img class="hidden" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="" />
<img class="hidden" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="" />
<br />

<button type="button" onclick="showimage()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Really sorry to all for not providing code. I am new here and wasn't really thinking. Abney317, that did exactly what I wanted, so thank you dearly!

Comment: Using the same code you provided, is there a way to randomize which image shows up?

Comment: It is random. I just used the same image 5 times. Change the URLs to 5 different images.